# Translations of a subsequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We're given a sequence $u_n$ and a subsequence $u_{\phi(n)}$. Let $L$ be fixed.

Suppose that for all $k \in \mathbb{N}^*$, the subsequence $u_{\phi(n)+k}$ (the "translation of $u_{\phi(n)}$ by $k$") converges to $L$.

**Does it hold that $u_n$ converges to $L$?**

---

Intuitively, this seems true.

Given two subsequences $u_{a(n)}$ and $u_{b(n)}$ which both converge to $l$, define $S=a(\mathbb{N})\bigcup b(\mathbb{N})$ and define $c(n)$ as the function which outputs the elements of $S$ in increasing order. We'll call the subsequence $u_{c(n)}$ the "union" of the two subsequences $u_{a(n)}$ and $u_{b(n)}$.

Its easy to show that $u_{c(n)}$ converges to $L$: for all $\epsilon>0$ there exist $(N_a,N_b)$ s.t $n \ge N_a \implies |u_{a(n)}-L|<\epsilon$ and $n \ge N_b \implies |u_{b(n)}-L|<\epsilon$. Since $c(n)$ is increasing, for $n$ sufficiently large, $c(n) \ge \max\{a(N_a), b(N_b)\}$ and thus $|u_{c(n)}-L| \le \epsilon$.

By induction, the "union" of finitely many subsequences which converge to $L$, also converges to $L$.

The question now is, is the same true for infinitely many subsequences?

If so, we are done. It's easy to show that the union of all the translations of $u_{\phi(n)}$ is a subsequence of the form $u_{N_0+n}$ for some fixed $N_0$. (The translations effectively cover $\mathbb{N}$, except for finitely many elements).  It's then clear that $u_n$ converges to $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a counterexample, let $$u_n=\begin{cases}0, \text{ if }n\text{ is a power of }2,
\\1,\text{ otherwise,}\end{cases}$$

and let $\phi(n)=2^n.$

---

Take $\phi(n)=2^n+1$ instead if you want to allow a translation by $0,$ as indicated in a comment.

Comment: Hmm very clever to use the fact that $2^n=2^m+k$ has finitely many solutions for $(n,m)$ for a given $k$. I think the general idea works, but just so you know $u_{\phi(n)}$ converges to $0$, and for all $k \ge 1$, $u_{\phi(n)+k}$ converges to $1$. So this sequence doesn't quite fit the conditions of the problem (as $U_{\phi(n)}$ is considered to be a translation of itself) . But $\phi(n)=2^n+1$ does work!

Comment: Am I missing something? Take $L=1.$ Then, for all $k\ge 1,$ $u_{\phi(n)+k}$ converges to  $L,$  but $u_n$ does not converge to $L.$ (You didn't have any requirement on $u_{\phi(n)}.)$

Comment: Isn't $\mathbb{N}^*$ the set of positive integers?

Comment: I added to the answer to take into account the slight modification (or explanation) of the question.

Comment: I thought $\mathbb{N}$ was the set of positive integers and $\mathbb{N}^*$ the set of non-negative integers. In either case it's just a indexing thing. More importantly, how did you come up with this counter example?

Comment: I think some people may use the notation $\mathbb{N}^*$ that way; I'm just used to it the other way around. In any case, I'm really not sure how I came up with the answer -- it was literally the first thing that popped into my head when I saw the question. (Sorry, I know that's not very helpful.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u_n=1$ if $n$ is a power of $2$; otherwise let $2^k$ be the greatest power of $2$ less than $n$, and let $u_{n}=1+\frac{n-2^k}{k}$. Now we consider $\phi(n)=2^n,$ and see that for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and sufficiently high $n$ we have \begin{align}u_{\phi(n)+k}=1+\frac{k}{n}&\to 1,\\
u_{\phi(n)-1}=1+\frac{2^n-1}{n}&\to\infty,\end{align}
and hence $u_n$ does not converge.